# How to get local time on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I just noticed that `NSDate *nowDate = [NSDate date];` gives me GMT+0 Time and not the local time. So basically on my iPad it's 13:00 and the output of this code is 12:00.

How do I get local time properly?

Comment: Try this link, it allows you to get local time zone. http://buildingmyworld.wordpress.com/2011/04/13/get-local-time-from-iphone-local-nsdate/

Comment: How are you getting the "output of this code"? Are you using an NSDateFormatter to get a string or are you just `NSLog`ging the NSDate object?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Give it a Shot !

```
NSDate* sourceDate = [NSDate date];

NSTimeZone* sourceTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
NSTimeZone* destinationTimeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];//use `[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]` if your users will be changing time-zones. 

NSInteger sourceGMTOffset = [sourceTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:sourceDate];
NSInteger destinationGMTOffset = [destinationTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:sourceDate];
NSTimeInterval interval = destinationGMTOffset - sourceGMTOffset;

NSDate* destinationDate = [[[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:interval sinceDate:sourceDate] autorelease];
```

It will give you the time according to the current system timezone.

Comment: why is it so bloody complicated. -1 for iOS!

Comment: its not complicated. Time is Time is Time. The format of time is hard because humans created timezones.  So that 6:00 pm around the world would be evening.

Comment: This will give you a point in time `x hours` ago or in the future, not the current time.

Comment: This code worked for me

Comment: **WARNING!** It is very important to call `resetSystemTimeZone` method before you call `systemTimeZone` method, due to the caching of the timezone for the entire life of the application. See Apple's description for the `systemTimeZone` method.

Comment: Or just use `localTimeZone`

Answer (score 6):

NSDate does not care about timezones. It simply records a moment in time.

You should set the local timezone when using the NSDateFormatter to get a string representation of the date:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle]; // Set date and time styles
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Comment: and then what? Should I convert NSSTring to NSDate again? Doesn't look much efficient

Comment: If you need an NSDate then just use `[NSDate date]` - it doesn't care about timezones. I suggest you read the Date and Time Programming Guide - https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000039i

Comment: Thats the problem I need an NSDate object that cares ;)

Comment: @amergin thanks - edited

Answer (score 5):

```
 NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
 [calendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
 NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
 NSDate *d = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComponents];
```

Answer (score 4):

```
// get current date/time
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
// display in 12HR/24HR (i.e. 11:25PM or 23:25) format according to User Settings
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
NSString *currentTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:today];
[dateFormatter release];
NSLog(@"%@",currentTime);
```