# I want to show current time on a label with time format hh:mm:ss

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

A current time format should be like hh:mm:ss and seconds should run ,the seconds should not stop counting, it should keep on running let me show you what code i am writing.

```
-(void)timeNotify
{
NSDate *currDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss a"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currDate];

_timeLbl.text=dateString;

}
```

and in view did load i am calling this

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
  [self timeNotify];
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: when i run the app , label is displaying current date with format hh:mm:ss but the problem is time is not changing. it is only changing when you refresh the app. i want the time should change continuously once the app is launched. Means seconds digit should keep on changing 00, 01, 02, 03 and so on. i hope you get it..?

Comment: Possible duplication of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15615637/how-to-get-local-time-on-ios

Comment: Have you tried a timer?  This question has been asked and answered uncounted times.

Comment: @Avi no i didn't tried timer., you are right i need time only.

Comment: will answer in swift work?

Comment: no i want in obj-c @HarshalBhavsar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `NSTimer` :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(timeNotify)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:YES];
}

- (void) timeNotify
{
    NSDate *currentTime = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss"];
    NSString *resultString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: currentTime];
    _timeLbl.text = resultString;
}
```

Comment: thanks Diana Prodan, for solving my issue... it really worked..

Comment: please accept my answer if it solved your problem

Comment: i have already upvoted you ...

Comment: Thank you so much for both question and answer..

Answer (score -1):

You should use an `NSTimer` if you want your time periodically updated

```
NSTimer* timer =       [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                   target:self
                                 selector:@selector(timeNotify)
                                 userInfo:nil
                                  repeats:YES];
```

Remember to set `timer` to `nil` when the view disappear because timer is keeping reference to your ViewController and so it will lead to memory leak if you don't destroy it

Comment: Thanks for your answer....

Comment: If it solve your problem, don't forget to up answer and mark it a your resolution ;) thx

Comment: i have upvoted you..

Answer (score -2):

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
// display in 12HR/24HR (i.e. 11:25PM or 23:25) format according to User Settings
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
NSString *currentTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:today];
NSLog(@"User's current time in their preference format:%@",currentTime);
```

Comment: it does'nt work bro.

Comment: I m not given the down vote, once check the question exactly ,questioner need the timer

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik  i have not down voted you dear.

Comment: who down voted my answer? A person trying to help and you are guys are there to have a jealousy about increase in the repo.

Comment: @Kiran thanks for your comment but it really doesn't work , seconds digit is static , not changing... dynamically..

Comment: You guys down voting everyone who is trying to help? Morons